# Generate preview thumbnails of all images in a directory for nemo

Tags: thumbnails, nemo, previews

I would like to be able to force nemo to create preview thumbnails for all images in a directory, not just the ones for the currently visible icons. The reason is I have some folders with thousands of pictures and I would like to be able quickly scroll up and down to inspect them. As it is now I have to wait a long time for all the preview thumbnails to be generated/rendered each time I scroll down to look at more pictures. I'd rather let all this preview processing be done at once in the background.